# How to use a for..of and async await inside each iteration replacing let..of

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Using a list of search keywords stored in CSV file, using let keyword of searchkeywords, how do I modify to have forEach?

Viewed every listed similar question, none provided a solution.

Set a constant

```
const searchkeywords = readKeyWords('./datain.csv','utf-8');
```

Using inside async function main

```
for (let keyword of searchkeywords)
```

Hope to use

```
listofkeywords.forEach(sync (keyword) => {
```

Cannot discover how to modify.

Comment: Is there a reason to use `.forEach` over `for...of`? You also don't show what you are trying to call in those loops that is `async`.

Comment: @crashmstr , How would I set the const to the file?  I tried:

`    async function printFiles () {
            const files = await getFilePaths('./datain/testdata.csv','utf-8');

            for (let file of files) {
                const contents = await fs.readFile(file, 'utf8');
                console.log(contents);
            }
        }    `

it does not return any data in console.log

Comment: Could not format code properly, above.

Comment: @TahorSuiJuris You might want to [edit] your question to include the relevant code. Btw, you might want to `console.log(files)` to check whether it is an empty array, and then fix `getFilePaths`?

Comment: @Bergi above is the relevant code, tried ` tried 4 spaces, the code is not posting as code.

Comment: @TahorSuiJuris In comments, only `\`inline code\`` works. For posting larger chunks of code, use the body of your question.

Comment: @Bergi posted as a new question:  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56484600/how-would-i-set-define-the-const-files)

Comment: You should just have [edit]ed this question, but well... let's continue over there.