# How would I set/define the const files?

Tags: javascript, async-await

How to set/ define the const files?

Have tried placing the path and CSV file location in () but does not return value.

```
        const searchkeywords = readKeyWords('./datain/testdata.csv','utf-8'); // database

        function readKeyWords(path) {
        return fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf-8')
            .split('\n');
    }

        async function printFiles () {
            const files = await getFilePaths();

            for (const file of files) {
                const contents = await fs.readFile(file, 'utf8');
                console.log(contents);
            }
        }
```

Hoping to achieve sequential iteration, serial processing.

Comment: Your code looks correct. Could you add details what the problem is?

Comment: What exactly does not work? Did you debug the value of `files` or of `searchkeywords`? How is `getFilePaths` defined?

Comment: @junvar getFilesPaths() is not defined, that is the problem

Comment: Your code looks good, but where are you calling the printFiles function ?

Comment: @TahorSuiJuris So then define it to be whatever you need? The question is really unclear.

Comment: Tried `printFiles(searchkeywords)` returns error
(node:5960) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: getFilePaths is not defined

Comment: Have set data source to const:
`const searchkeywords = readKeyWords('./datain/testdata.csv','utf-8');`
Have parsed CSV file:
`     function readKeyWords(path) {
        return fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf-8')
            .split('\n');`

Have async iteration function:
`        async function printFiles () {
            const files = await getFilePaths();

            for (const file of files) {
                const contents = await fs.readFile(file, 'utf8');
                console.log(contents);
            }
        }`
Tried to call printFiles:
`printFiles(searchkeywords)`

Comment: Well it looks like you want `files` to be **a parameter of `printFiles`**, instead of calling an undeclared `getFilePaths` function? Seems like you need to learn the basics of function calls - the "*sequential iteration, serial processing*" part already does work as expected.

Comment: @Bergi have already set `const searchkeywords = readKeyWords('./datain/testdata.csv','utf-8');'

How can I set again to reference the data source?

Comment: So you just want `const files = searchkeywords` or what? Not sure what you mean by "*reference the data source*".

Comment: @Bergi does nothing in regards to the function, but the below does (not sequential iteration)
`const files = searchkeywords;`
`console.log(files);`

[screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/9aiGQTO.png)
Red does not work.  Green returns console.log

Comment: @TahorSuiJuris  http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html

Comment: @Bergi, thank you... resolved the problem, in the for..let async loop, all that was required was a await page which halts feeding of the entire CSV file into the input field, which relates to the original challenge.